# Excluding all data above a percentile for different categories

Tags: python, pandas, percentile

I have a dataframe with different categories and want to exclude all the values which are above a given percentile for each category.

```
d = {'cat': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
     'val': [1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 7]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

  cat  val
0  A    1
1  B    2
2  A    4
3  A    2
4  C    1
5  C    0
6  B    9
7  A    8
8  B    7
9  C    7
```

So for example, excluding the 0.95 percentile should result in:

```
  cat  val
0  A    1
1  B    2
2  A    4
3  A    2
4  C    1
5  C    0
8  B    7
```

because we have:

```
>>> df[df['cat']=='A'].quantile(0.95).item()
7.399999999999999

>>> df[df['cat']=='B'].quantile(0.95).item()
8.8

>>> df[df['cat']=='C'].quantile(0.95).item()
6.399999999999999
```

In reality there are many categories and I need a neat way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `quantile` function in combination with `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('cat')['val'].apply(lambda x: x[x < x.quantile(0.95)]).reset_index().drop(columns='level_1')
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution:

```
idx = [False] * df.shape[0]
for cat in df['cat'].unique():
    idx |= ((df['cat']==cat) & (df['val'].between(0, df[df['cat']==cat ].quantile(0.95).item())))

df[idx]
```

but it would be nice to see other solutions (hopefully better ones).